# Long Polling, send updates to several users

Tags: tomcat, asynchronous, tomcat7, long-polling

I am building a *tomcat server application with real time updates*. I am using asynchronous context to send updates to the user. So the request is kept open until there is some news or update for the channel. When the news is arrived, several online subscribers need to be notified about the news. The problem is how can I send the updates to all the subscribers, from the same request sent by some user who updated the news. Should I execute a new thread per subscriber?

PS I have learnt about proper long polling implementation from this tutorial: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/async-servlet/async-servlets.html